# How can I secure my database connections to Oracle?

Tags: security, oracle10g, database-connection

We have an .net application that we are considering deploying over a WAN connection.  One worry is around the security of connections to the oracle database.  What methods are there to secure database connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle Advanced Security option ($) enables encryption of application-to-Oracle connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using enterprise edition you can use native encryption https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e40393/asoconfg.htm#ASOAG9592 .
If you are on enterprise edition you can also pay for the advanced security option license if you want authentication along with data encryption (SSL, TLS).

The features comparison page that Oracle has states that security options are not available for standard edition. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/editions.htm#DBLIC116

I've implemented encryption for data in transit, data at rest, and TLS for 11.2 and 12.1. If you have any questions feel free to ask.